# Translation of the C++ "move constructor" language element

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

The [C++ programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) has several types of constructors (functions invoked when an object is being created):

- Default constructor: *constructor por defecto*.
- Copy constructor: *constructor de copia*.

On the next revision of the language (C++11), there will be a new type of constructor called "move constructor". This constructor moves data from one temporal object to the new one.

However, I cannot find a proper translation, as *constructor de movimiento* or *construcción de traslado* sounds strange.

What would be an accurate way to translate this language element?

Comment: Although _constructor de movimiento_ is "closer" to _move constructor_, _constructor de traslado_ implies its meaning correctly. I did not post this as an answer because I am just giving my opinion on your current suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic but I'm into C++ and haven't heard of move-constructors, how is it different from a copy constructor? it *deletes* the original object or something?

Comment: It allows to transfer resources from the object being copied. It is normally invoked when copying  temporal objects that are going to be destroyed afterwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that «constructor de movimiento» is more used, even in [Espawiki](http://espawiki.com/wiki/Funciones_miembro_especiales), where they say:

> Constructor de copia y constructor de movimiento se definen por el
>   compilador, a menos que uno de ellos sea definido explícitamente

«Constructor de traslado» is a very fair translation, and may be it's more appropriate, but it's not so used.

Comment: :Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you going.